# How to prevent user type in input textbox more than specified number of input character in angular?

Tags: angular

i use textarea tag and i want when user type in that, she can not type more than forexample 300 character. i write code and i have real time character number that user type but i want when it comes to 300 character she can not type anymore.

here is my html code:

```
<textarea type="text" style="margin-bottom: 25px"
                    id="textAreaScroll"
                    formControlName="text"
                    placeholder="متن ..."
                    (keyup)="postLengthCheck()">
          </textarea>
          <span *ngIf="createPostForm.controls['text'].valid" class="text-counter">{{validTextLength}}</span>
```

and here is my `postLengthCheck()` method im my component:

```
postLengthCheck() {

      if (this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value !== null) {
        this.postLength = this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value.length;
        this.validTextLength = 2200 - this.postLength;
      }
  }
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Just use `maxlength='300'` property in your `<textarea>` that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `maxlength='300'` prop in you `<textarea>` like this

```
 <textarea type="text" style="margin-bottom: 25px"
                id="textAreaScroll"
                formControlName="text"
                placeholder="متن ..."
                maxLength="300">
      </textarea>
```

if you are reading the value from `Component` class just use attribute binding in `[maxlength]='your_prop_name'` - this might work

Thanks happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a maxLength validator when creating your `formControl` like this :

```
new FormControl('text', [Validators.maxLength(100)]);
```

Regards,

Comment: thank you for your answer but my main problem is i want user can not type in textbox anymore in this situation and i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `[maxLength]="'300'"`

```
<textarea type="text" style="margin-bottom: 25px"
                id="textAreaScroll"
                formControlName="text"
                placeholder="متن ..."
                (keyup)="postLengthCheck()"
                 [maxLength]="'300'"`>
      </textarea>
```